# how to scroll screen in flutter? (vertically Scrollable)

Tags: flutter, scrollview

this is my code

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: Scaffold(
            body: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                SizedBox.fromSize(size: Size.fromHeight(25)),
                actionBar(context, currentAddress),
                buildFloatingSearchBar(context),
                Container(
```

Comment: Can you include full sample widget, like here `buildFloatingSearchBar` is unkwon.

Answer (score 0):

Try `SingleChildScrollView()` widget.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: Scaffold(
            body: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                SizedBox.fromSize(size: Size.fromHeight(25)),
                actionBar(context, currentAddress),
                buildFloatingSearchBar(context),
                Container(
```

Comment: but screen showing white ,not display content

Comment: You need to fill Column. When you add enough widget to overflow the screen in your Column, it will be scrolled.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your Column into SingleChildScrollView

```
 body:  SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
                    children: [
```